# Regex find/replace string with quoted string

Tags: regex, notepad++, find-replace

I can find a way to replace a string within quotes but I can not find a way to add quotes to a string with find/replace in notepad++

So I have a .sql file that I copy and pasted a bunch of insert values. The strings are not in quotations like they need to be.

I have the find statement as `\s\w{1,}` and it works fine for me but if I use "\1" it just replaces with ""

Is there a way to get each string replaced to a string with quotes like STRING replaced to "STRING"

Comment: Use `$0` or `\0` or capture your match into a group to use `\1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to replace your STRING with "STRING" in notepade++, you can try this to put in find area `\s(\w{1,})` and this `"$1"` in replace area.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is the answer, i thought I tried the $1 reference but i think having (\w{1,}) in parenthesis made the difference  Thank you